# How to add an ID in Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have set up a page with modal's but at the moment it only works with having one modal on the page.

What I would like to achieve is apply id in the Jquery so each modal has it's own ID and opens with multiple modals.

HTML:

```
<a class="activator1" id="activator1"><img class="edit_icon" align="right" src="/images/edit_icon.png" alt="">Edit</a>
<div class="box1" id="box1">
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    <p>Text in here</p>
</div>`
<a class="activator2" id="activator2"><img class="edit_icon" align="right" src="/images/edit_icon.png" alt="">Edit</a>
<div class="box2" id="box2">
    <h3>Title here</h3>
    <p>Text in here</p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('#activator').click(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
            $('#box').animate({'top':'80px'},500);
        });
    });
    $('#boxclose').click(function(){
        $('#box').animate({'top':'-1400px'},500,function(){
            $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use unique classes, keep them common for common elements. Use secondary classes if needed for styling

A simple data attribute can be used for the target and can be read using `data()` method

```
<a class="activator" id="activator1" data-target="#box1>
```

Then use class for click handler selector

```
$('.activator').click(function(){
   // "this" is element event occurred on
   var modalTargetSelector = $(this).data('target');
   $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
        $(modalTargetSelector ).animate({'top':'80px'},500);
   });

});
```

Similarly for close buttons use common class and do something like:

```
 $('.boxclose').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.box').animate({'top':'-1400px'},500,function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

Comment: Legend! Many thanks for your answer it works perfectly to how I want it too.

Comment: Should open you up to a slightly different way of thinking regarding repeating components also